# cannot send email with attachment from python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

msg = MIMEMultipart('multipart/related')

fromaddr = 'from@gmail.com'
toaddrs = 'to@gmail.com'


#provide gmail user name and password
username = 'to@gmail.com'
password = 'messifan'

filename = "1.jpg"
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEImage(f.read()) # error here
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
.
.
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
```

i am using this code to send email. i can attach text file using this script.(chenging MIMEImage to MIMEtext). but cannot attach image. **the error is Could not guess Image mime subtype**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a bit of a guess here, but maybe try opening the file in binary mode?

```
f = file(filename, 'rb')
```

Comment: thats problem solved. Now error in this line
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())

Comment: I think (again not testing as I'm going) that you need to pass the toaddrs as a list

Comment: like this toaddrs = ['to@gmail.com'] ? pls help me

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
attachment = MIMEImage(f.read(), _subtype="jpeg") # error here
```

Comment: In my case, `... _subtype="svg+xml" ...`

Comment: it doesn't matter as long as the server doesn't have to guess what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you created a "file" object, but you never opened it.

Where you have:

```
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEImage(f.read()) # error here
```

I think you instead need:

```
fp = open(filename, 'rb')
attachment = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
```

Comment: the method "file" opens the file.